# Wing and horizontal/vertical tailplane airfoil type and relative thickness?

Tags: wing, boeing-737, airbus-a320, airfoil, tail

I've been searching for data on the airfoil type (namely if they are supercritical, aft-loading etc.) and relative thickness (average or in different positions) of the empennage (both horizontal and vertical tailplane) and wing of the following airplanes:

A320/A319, B737, A220/Bombardier C Series , E195-E2.

I've found data on the A320's wing (was unable to find data on the other wings), and no data on any of the empennages. I've checked Jane's, Thorenbeek, APM's etc. Where can I find this information?